# Cómo actualizar un registro en rails con jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails

```js
$(".list-group-item").dblclick(function(){
        var activity_id = $(this).attr("activity_id"); //obtener el id de un elemento
        console.log(activity_id);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $.ajax({
            url:"/activities/" + activity_id + ".json",
            type:"GET",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            $("#activityNameModal").val(data.name);
            $("#activityDescription").val(data.description);
            $("#activityEndDate").val(data.enddate);
            $("#activityMember").val();

            }

        })

    });
```

```html
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Detalles de la actividad</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="formActivities">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nombre de la actividad</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="activityNameModal">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Descripción</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="activityDescription">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Término de la actividad</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="activityEndDate">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Miembros designados</label>
            <% Member.all.each do |member| %>
            <label id="activityMember"><%= check_box_tag("members[]", member.id) %><%= member.name %></label>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="updateActivity" data-dismiss="modal">Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta quitando el ".json" a la url, en type usa POST en vez de GET y agrega **data** y ahi pon la información que vas a actualizar. Quedando algo asi, solo cambia lo necesario en data:

```
$(".list-group-item").dblclick(function(){
        var activity_id = $(this).attr("activity_id"); //obtener el id de un elemento
        console.log(activity_id);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $.ajax({
            url:"/activities/" + activity_id,
            type: "POST",
            data: { model_name: { attr1: "Value1", attr2: "value2" } },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#activityNameModal").val(data.name);
                $("#activityDescription").val(data.description);
                $("#activityEndDate").val(data.enddate);
                $("#activityMember").val();
            }
        })
});
```

Comment: Gracias Oscar, si funciona.

Comment: @HarimCaballero por favor **[acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)**.